# Windows 10 assigning static ip address cuts off internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ipv4

When I run `ipconfig` at the command prompt on my `Windows 10 Home` machine, I get the following output which shows my ip address is `192.168.166.135` and gateway is `192.168.166.70`

I'm trying to change this to something that is more easy to remember like `192.168.100.100` since I run a few test websites on Virtual Box.

But, when I go to `Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections` and right click on the wireless adapter and select properties and assign IP Address `192.168.100.100`, Subnet Mask `255.255.255.0` and Default Gateway `192.168.100.50`, in `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`, my Internet connection stops working, so do my test sites running on Virtual Box.

How I change the IP addresses to something I want and still keep things working? Where am I going wrong here?

P. S. I'm using `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4` for the DNS servers.

```
C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ddf9:d551:41f0:27b%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::55e6:b7a9:c5be:8596%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.166.135
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.166.70

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing stuff without understanding the basic concepts.

IP addresses are handed out by the DHCP server, which is usually your
router. I see that you have already trafficked with the router, since
a network IP of `192.168.166.x` is totally non-standard.
In any case, these are now the kind of IPs that belong in your network

You need to remember that the gateway is the router itself.
Arbitrarily changing the gateway from `192.168.166.70` to
`192.168.100.50` just means that your computer is on a standalone
network of `192.168.100.x` that connects to nowhere.
And especially not to any device that is on `192.168.166.x`,
which is a totally different network.

I suggest to go back into the router via its login page.
Set its range to the more easily remembered `192.168.0.x` and
set the router itself to the standard `192.168.0.1`.
The router itself might have a mechanism for static IPs, so give
your computer the IP of `192.168.0.2`
*using the router*.

Study the concepts involved - the internet has lots and lots of tutorials
about the subject.

Comment: I don't have a router. It's just my laptop connecting to the internet via my phone's data service. Ubuntu Server is installed on Oracle VM.

Comment: All this should have been mentioned in your post, because it does change the details. However, the basics are the same : Either you replace "router" above by whatever hotspot software is provided by your phone, or if you don't have that much control in it, keep unchanged the gateway as `192.168.166.70` and just change your laptop's IP, keeping it in the right network, by giving it something like `192.168.166.100`.